# Onblur repite alert

Tags: javascript

tengo un onblur y cada vez que salgo de el me sale la alerta y no puedo salir de ahi.. Como puedo evitar que se repita?

```
addEventListener("blur", blur, true);
function blur() {
      document.getElementById("nombre").style.backgroundColor = ""; 
      alert("Has salido del campo");
}
<input type="text" name = "nombre" id="nombre">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás asignando el evento a la ventana y detecta cualquier evento `blur` (perder el foco) en los descendientes, (por ejemplo: al salir del campo) y en la ventana misma (cuando salta cada alerta).

Lo que debes hacer es obtener el campo y asignarle el evento:

```js
// Obtener elemento por ID
let campo = document.getElementById("nombre");
// Asignar evento al campo
campo.addEventListener("blur", blur, true);
function blur() {
    // Aquí puedes usar la misma variable para modificar estilo
    campo.style.backgroundColor = ""; 
    alert("Has salido del campo");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
```